# Copying File in AsyncTask seems to block UI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I copy a file from assets to the database folder. But the layout indicates the user that something is going on isn't shown.

If I replace the copying part white a Thread.sleeve() for testing the layout is shown as expected.

```
public class InitialActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = InitialActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqlite_src.db";
private final String DATABASE_FOLDER = "/databases/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    // Just for testing... make sure AsyncTask is called

    /*
    File file = this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    if(file.exists()) {

        RunMainActivity();

    }
    */

}

private void RunMainActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    CopyFileFromAsset task = new CopyFileFromAsset(this);
    task.execute();

}

private class CopyFileFromAsset extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    private Context ctx = null;

    private CopyFileFromAsset(Context c) {

        this.ctx = c;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {

        if(aBoolean)
            RunMainActivity();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // Just for testing... in this case the layout is shown

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return true;

        // When copying the file the layout is NOT shown

        /*
        File file = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        Log.d(TAG, "File " + file.toString());
        File folder = file.getParentFile();
        Log.d(TAG, "Folder " + folder.toString());
        if(!folder.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder doesn't exist");
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return file.exists();
        */

    }

}
```

And my simple layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_initial"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="de.testapp.InitialActivity">

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Create Database..."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
```

Comment: Where is the AsyncTask? And where is the code that starts it running?

Comment: Have you verified that the file operation was indeed successful and hence returns true?

Comment: use rxjava instead of asynctask

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice The AsyncTask is in the Activity and is beeing started in Activity.OnStart()

Comment: @Joseph File operation is successfull

Comment: @olf What value does return file.exists(); come back with?

Comment: @ Joseph file.exists() returns true because copying the file is working

Comment: Finally I found the problem: Android Studio INSTANT RUN shows a white screen while the AsyncTask is already finished